# How do I get getString in fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, getstring

How do I get getString in fragment, I have tried to solve it with snippets of code on this but it did not work to tap

**chronology**
-ok so in the uploaded image there are some 6 items in the recyclerview that line up the grid, I try to make it to the String of the name as I have included the code but the code I press [commant + tap] displays the message {public statuc int} , but it can't be tapped to go to the next page, but if I try to use the usual string as I have included the code, it works on the next page

get an error  *public static int*

```
dataProduct.add(Products(R.drawable.ic_electricity, getString(R.string.electricity), true))
```

I've looked for a solution in this forum but it still hasn't worked, but if I use the code below it works

```
 dataProduct.add(Products(R.drawable.ic_electricity, "Electricity", true))
```

maybe I'll send a picture, below, in this case I will take the string but can't be tapped like the image below

[image getString](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5gFz.png)

Comment: Can you clarify, is this a compiler error, and what is the full text? What do you mean by "did not work to tap"?

Comment: ok so in the uploaded image there are some 6 items in the recyclerview that line up the grid, I try to make it to the String of the name as I have included the code but the code I press [commant + tap] displays the message {public statuc int} , but it can't be tapped to go to the next page, but if I try to use the usual string as I have included the code, it works on the next page @Tenfour04

Answer (score 1):

`getString()` is a method that comes from a context. In a fragment, this context is commonly provided by the activity hosting the fragment. To use the activity to get a resource, just call `getActivity()` (which in Kotlin can be written just as `activity`):

```
activity.getString(…)
```

Comment: I tried this code but it didn't work dataProduct.add(Products(R.drawable.ic_mobile_credit, activity.getString(R.string.mobile_credit), true)) @RedBassett

Comment: Can you add the error that you are seeing to your question? What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: can't be tapped, this display -> V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service @RedBassett